# ASP.Net MVC no response on certain HTTP Posts

Tags: asp.net-mvc

- ASP.Net MVC 4  .Net 4.5 application
- No problem submitting on "small" HTTP Posts.
- It seems that "larger" HTTP Post requests get no response.
- Happens on all browsers and from different devices.
- No errors, just no response.  ("The connection was reset")
- IIS 8 logs show the Post was received
- Works fine on my dev machine: Windows 8, IIS 8.

Tried

- Changing maxRequestLength to 50000 (kb)
- New empty ASP.Net MVC Project with one controller, and one action to test the HTTP post behavior.  Same issue.
- Log every application_... event: nothing logged on posts with no response.
- Setup new web server VS 2012 IIS 8 on a different VPS host: same problem.
- Tried triggering an error with 10K characters of text submitted, and maxRequestLength set to 1 (kb).  "Maximum request length exceeded" exception thrown on dev machine, but to response on hosting.

So...

1. What else should I try?
2. Possible causes of this "no response"?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is the issue with large post, normally its not recommended to post that big data over network because there are chances that packets can be lost on the way, this is a general issue.

The maxRequestLength indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET, the maxAllowedContentLength specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by IIS. Hence, we need to set both maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength values to upload large files.
Source : http://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx
So give a play around with maxAllowedContentLength

Comment: Nipun: you're answer was ripped from the following IIS.net post...was it not? Credit where credit is due!
http://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I neglected to try.

- Attempt to HTTP Post from a browser in a different country.
- Attempt to HTTP Post from a browser behind a different Internet Service Provider.

In this instance it turned out to be a caching problem at my local ISP.